# Low Search: Filter results by Collections

Tags: low-search

I want to only search results from specific collection on specific search results pages.

My search results is basically like the Low Search Results example

```
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" limit="10"}
{if count ==  1}<ol>{/if}
<li><a href="{url_title_path="#"}">{title}</a></li>
{if count == total_results}</ol>{/if}
{if no_results}No search results{/if}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

This shows me matching results from all saved collections. However, I only want to show results from a specific collection.

I see Low has the variable:

```
{collections}{/collections}
```

just not sure how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a specific form to search for a single collection the best option would be to pass a hidden input in the search form

```
{exp:low_search:form}
 <input type="hidden" name="collection" value="collection_name">
 <input type="search" name="keywords" placeholder="Search">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

You should also be able to do this on the results loop too but I haven't tested it. From your code above:

```
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" collection="collection_name_here" limit="10"}
  {if count ==  1}<ol>{/if}
    <li><a href="{url_title_path="#"}">{title}</a></li>
  {if count == total_results}</ol>{/if}
  {if no_results}No search results{/if}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Comment: thanks justin. that only worked if I put:

    collection="collection_name"

in the results tag.

Comment: I updated my code with another solution.

Comment: The hidden input field that Justin suggested should work, too. If it doesn't, open up a ticket at [my support page](http://getsatisfaction.com/low).